# Heredoc error, showing Parse error

Tags: php

The code below is showing a parse error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE 
or T_END_HEREDOC 
or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES 
or T_CURLY_OPEN in D:\xampp\htdocs\project1\conf.php 
on line 10
```

This is my code in the conf.php file

```
$chat_code = 
<<<EOD

<script>alert('Hi')</script>

EOD;
```

Comment: Code, that you provided, displays no errors. Check that `EOD;` has no leading symbols.

Comment: You need a new-line character after `EOD;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> **Warning:** It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier
>   must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). **That means
>   especially that the identifier may not be indented, and there may not
>   be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also
>   important to realize that the first character before the closing
>   identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system.**
>   This is \n on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X. **The closing delimiter
>   must also be followed by a newline.** If this rule is broken and the
>   closing identifier is not "clean", it will not be considered a closing
>   identifier, and PHP will continue looking for one. If a proper closing
>   identifier is not found before the end of the current file, a parse
>   error will result at the last line. Heredocs can not be used for
>   initializing class properties. Since PHP 5.3, this limitation is valid
>   only for heredocs containing variables.

So your heredoc string closing delimiter should have no leading symbols and no following symbols, except new line symbol.